# Fast method for Looping through Array to match a common ID in a second array

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to systematically loop through 2 arrays, and match their values for some quick processing.  Let me set up my specific situation:

**Array 1**
productID,
companyID,
name,
price

**Array 2**
companyID,
name,
rebate1,
rebate2

I want to loop through `Array 1`, and when the `companyID` matches an ID inside of `Array 2`, I will do some quick math based on the `rebate1, rebate2` values for that `companyID`.

Right now I am looping through `Array 1`, and then on EACH item in `Array 1` I loop through the entire `Array 2` to see if the `companyID` exists.  I know this can't be the fastest/cleanest solution...

**EDIT**

The key values for `Array 1` look like:

```
$array1[0]['productID']
$array1[0]['companyID']  (etc...)
$array1[1]['productID']
$array1[1]['companyID']  (etc...)
```

The key values for `Array 2` look like:

```
$array2[0]['companyID']
$array2[0]['rebate1']  (etc...)
$array2[1]['companyID']
$array2[1]['rebate1']  (etc...)
```

Comment: Transform array 2 into `array(companyID => company information)`? Key lookups with `isset` or `array_key_exists` are going to be significantly faster.

Comment: What are the keys and values of **Array 1**? What are the keys and values of **Array 2**? Or, in other words, what do you mean by ***Array 1** productID, companyID, name, price* and ***Array 2** companyID, name, rebate1, rebate2*

Comment: Instead of the nested loops, why not use array_intersect? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: @DevlshOne Because the array values fail to compare properly.

Comment: @DCoder I think I understand, so basically do what you say with Oswald's answer...Let me wrap my head around this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `companyId` as key for **Array 2**, i.e., make sure that

```
$Array2[$Array1[$i]['companyID']]['companyID'] == $Array1[$i]['companyID']
```

This gives you constant time lookup of companies in **Array 2** based on `companyID` and you can do your calculation with

```
$Array2[$Array1[$i]['companyID']]['rebate1']`
```

and

```
$Array2[$Array1[$i]['companyID']]['rebate2']`
```

**Example:**

```
foreach ($Array1 as $value) {
  if (isset($Array2[$value['companyID']])) {
    //TODO: use $Array2[$value['companyID']] for calculation
  } else {
    // TODO: handle case companyID not in $Array2
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that with this method, I still have a `foreach` inside of a `foreach` - do I not?  Because I need to test every value in `array1` vs. every value in `array2`

Comment: @Shackrock No, you don't.

Comment: So in your example, you're assuming `array2` only has one value in it.  Remember, `array2` has 100's of values too.  `$array2[0]['companyID']`, `$array2[1]['companyID']`, `$array2[3]['companyID']`, etc...

Comment: I assume (or rather, I suggested) that `$array2` is not index based on natural number 0, 1, 2, etc, but instead based on `companyID`. So that `$array2[$i]['companyID'] == $i`.

Answer (score 1):

What approximate sizes do you expect for each of your arrays?

While as you say, your method isn't certainly the fastest (looks like 0(n²)), below 10'000 elements in each array I doubt you can see any significant speed difference.

If you have 150'000 in array1 and 200'000 in array2, that's a whole other story and you'll have to look for an algorithm that is rather 0(log n).

**Edit:**

As mentioned above, let's just make your array associative if you can:

Instead of:

```
Array2 = array(
    0 => array(
        'Company_id' => 'Hello',
        'rebate_1' => '50%',
    )
);
```

Make it:

```
Array2 = array(
    'Hello' => array(
        'rebate_1' => '50%',
    )
);
```

And then use:

```
if (isset(array2[$company_id]))
{
    // do your stuff
}
```

If you can't modify Array2's structure where it's coming from, you should transform it on the fly in your search function's scope, so that it looks like above, and then use the transformed array. Transforming Array2 into an associative one shouldn't take too long, for the number of elements you say you have.

Comment: 1,000's for `array1`, and 100's for `aray2` - which would yeild something in the 100,000's range once they loop inside a loop.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments to your OP, if I were you I would check if I can modify Array2 to be associative, see my edit above

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to use the companyID as the key for Array 2:

```
$companies[$companyID]=array($name,$rebate1,$rebate2)
```

and then you just reference it directly looping Array 1

```
$products[$x]=array($productID,$companyID,$name,$price);
...
$newprice1=$products[$x][3]/$companies[$products[$x][1]][1];
$newprice2=$products[$x][3]/$companies[$products[$x][1]][2];
```

My answer is slightly different from the first one, mind the arrays...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array indexed by the company id as follows:

```
$cid = array_map(function($a) {return $a['companyID'];}, $array2);
$new2 = array_combine($cid, $array2);
```

With that, you can loop through the first array and access the data:

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value){
    $rebate1 = $new2[$value['companyID']]['rebate1'];
    $rebate2 = $new2[$value['companyID']]['rebate2'];
}
```